# SNAP update is doing this often now

Tags: updates

Sorry if the title is wrong.   I don't know better.

Recently I am getting messages about SNAP updates (well, ok maybe not SNAP, but "software" updates) for programs needing to be done.

There are two options:  Do each one, one at a time, or "update all".
Which ever - and I am going now for "update all" as I can't be bothered watching/waiting/hoping it will all go through - maybe one, two or some work then I get this message:

[image: the message I see after some/one programs have updated.]

And what am I supposed to do now?  (Rhetorical)

Next time maybe the update is there, sometimes not.

Seems a bit weird.